# gradle test for akka with testkit

Tags: scala, gradle, akka, akka-testkit

I have a Scala + Akka + Gradle application and the following test:

```
class UserCRUDSpec() extends TestKit(ActorSystem("UserCRUDSpec"))
  with ImplicitSender
  with WordSpecLike
  with Matchers
  with Mockito
  with DomainSuit {

  val userDao: UserDao = mock[UserDao]
  val actor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(UserCRUD.props(self, userDao))

  "The UserCRUD actor " must {

    "search actor by id if actorId specified and exists" in {
       ...
    }

  }

}
```

and a gradle `build.gradle` dependencies:

```
    apply plugin: 'scala'

    dependencies {
        compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.12.6'
        compile('com.typesafe.akka:akka-cluster_2.12:2.5.14') {
            exclude group: 'org.scala-lang'
        }
        testCompile ('com.typesafe.akka:akka-testkit_2.12:2.5.14') {
            exclude group: 'org.scala-lang'
        }
        testCompile ('org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:3.0.5') {
            exclude group: 'org.scala-lang'
        }
        testCompile ('org.specs2:specs2-core_2.12:4.3.3') {
            exclude group: 'org.scala-lang'
        }
        testCompile ('org.specs2:specs2-mock_2.12:4.3.3') {
            exclude group: 'org.scala-lang'
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `./gradle test`, it says that no tests found. Is there any way how I can add TestKit tests to be visible for `gradle test` task?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I just switched to scalatest and specified actor system:

```
class UserCRUDSpec() extends WordSpec with TestKitBase ... {
  ...
  implicit lazy val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("UserCRUDSpec")
  ...
}
```